# my php script stops processing and outputting after executing a mysql select query that returns zero (0) rows

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code. When i try to insert a user which already exists, the query returns one row and the script work fine. but when the query returns zero row , the script stops at the point commented as "STOPS HERE" in the code below. Please I don't really understand the problem and I'm new to php. Even the echo statement outside the ifs are not executed.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["error"] = "";
include "dbconnection.php";

$_SESSION["validUser"] = 4; 

$validUser = $_SESSION["validUser"];


extract($_POST);

if($courseSession == ""){
    echo "You must Select a course session ";   
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE student = $validUser AND course='$courseSession'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db)  or die(mysql_error($db));

    if(!$result){
        echo " no results have been returned testing "; // used for testing
    }
    else {
        echo " Results returned but don't understand  \n Number rows = ";   // used for testing
        echo mysql_num_rows($result);

    } //STOPS HERE, here is where the script stops after query above returns 0 row.
    $check = mysql_num_rows($result)   or die(mysql_error($db));

    echo " after check course ";
    if($check){

        echo "You have already registered for this session "; 


    }

    else if(!$check){

        $query = "INSERT INTO courses
                            (course, student, groupId)

                        VALUES
                            ('$courseSession', '$validUser', '$group')";

        $res = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
        if(!$res){
            echo "Error Registering Course ";
        }
        else{
            echo "Successfully registered for this session ";
        }
    }
}


echo " TESting testing ";


?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Trying adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to the top of your file

Comment: You should accept the answer that was correct below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code with this line:

`$check = mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error($db));`.

When this runs, `mysql_num_rows($result)` returns 0, which evaluates the same as false in this case, and that is why `die()` is executed and nothing runs afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which might assist as an alternative:

```
$query = "SELECT Count(*) as ResultVal FROM courses WHERE student = $validUser AND course='$courseSession'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db)  or die(mysql_error($db));

if($result["ResultVal"] > 0){
       echo "You have already registered for this session "; 
   }

    else if($result["ResultVal"] = 0){ //OR just else

        $query = "INSERT INTO courses

        //rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

try     $check = mysql_num_rows($result)   or die("hi control is here"); 
instead of  $check = mysql_num_rows($result)   or die(mysql_error($db));

If it prints "hi control is here" then this confirms that die is the problem.

Comment: that line is the source of the problem as explained by @user2408594. thanks